# How do I change my author name on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I'm new to web development and GitHub. When I commit any changes, these changes are reflected on my GitHub repo under "unknown (author)". How do I change this to reflect my name/email address?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: [How do I change the author of a commit in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/how-do-i-change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git).

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
$ git config --global user.name "Scott Chacon"
$ git config --global user.email "schacon@gmail.com"
```

Comment: You can also omit the `--global` flag if you only want to modify those settings for a particular repository. If I recall, any repository-specific configuration settings will override any global settings.

Answer (score 21):

Add something like this to a file called `~/.gitconfig` (in your home directory):

```
[user]
    name = USERNAME
    email = EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

where `USERNAME` and `EMAIL_ADDRESS` are filled in appropriately

Answer (score 6):

Note that starting Git 2.2 (Q3/Q4 2014), and [commit 9830534](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9830534e40bd15231357965441d4fe02a6a4810e) by [Matthieu Moy (`moy`)](https://github.com/moy), you will be naturally guided to enter a user and email:

### `config --global --edit`: create a template file if needed

> When the user has no `~/.gitconfig` file, `git config --global --edit` used
>   to launch an editor on an nonexistant file name.
>
> Instead, **create a file with a default content before launching the
>   editor**.
>   The template contains only commented-out entries, to save a few keystrokes for the user. If the values are guessed properly, the user will only have to uncomment the entries.
>
> Advanced users teaching newbies can create a minimalistic configuration faster for newbies.
>   Beginners reading a tutorial advising to run "`git config --global --edit`" as a first step will be slightly more guided for their first contact with Git.

---

If you put your GitHub username and email account in those settings, your commits will accurately reflect your GitHub account as the right author.

Note that the user.name and email are guessed and put in that /.gitconfig file, as per [commit 8b27ff7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8b27ff7eacc3bafcb12afcd6bbc99cdb8d718a26):

### commit: advertise `config --global --edit` on guessed identity

> When the user has no user-wide configuration file, it's faster to use the newly introduced config file template than to run two commands to set `user.name` and `user.email`. Advise this to the user.
>
> The old advice is kept if the user already has a configuration file since the template feature would not trigger in this case.

New advice:

> Your name and email address were configured automatically based on your username and hostname.
>   Please check that they are accurate.
>   You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit your configuration file:"

```
git config --global --edit
```

> After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: This still works in 2022. Because VSCode is set as my default editor for some file types, it opened automatically into it and I was able to update my Author name.

Answer (score 1):

Git uses your username to associate commits with an identity.
The git config command can be used to change your Git configuration, including your username.
Here is a good guide available:
https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/