# error while changing git author/committer name

Tags: git

I am trying to change the author name/email in my github commit. i found this script somewhere in google.

```
git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="pubmem";GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="pubmem@something.net";GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="pubmem";GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="pubmem@something.net";' HEAD
```

this give me error `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

how to fix this problem, any help would be appreciate?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Issue this command:

```
git status
```

Your unstaged changes should be listed there. Add them all with

```
git add .
```

or add them individually. 
To change author name, did you try [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007135/how-do-i-change-my-author-name-on-github)

Comment: Or, if you're not ready to add them, you can temporarily move them out of the way by calling `git stash`. When you are finished with your operations, you can restore those changes with `git stash pop`.